# Postgresql : Mark the first row of a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, case

I have a table t like this :

```
id | group_id | name
------------------------
1  |    1     | richard
2  |    1     | ray
3  |    2     | enzo
4  |    2     | shiela
5  |    2     | anne
```

I have no problem selecting each group, however I want to mark the first occurrence for each group by group_id. Then add it as column to mark that the row is the first occurrence of that group.

E.g, Richard for group 1, or Enzo for group 2 and so on.

I should be able to use:

```
         select
         t.* 
           case
           when (condition)
           ...(boolean result here)
           end as is_first_row
         from t
```

and result to :

```
id | group_id | name    |is_first_row
-------------------------------
1  |    1     | richard | t
2  |    1     | ray     | f
3  |    2     | enzo    | t
4  |    2     | shiela  | f
5  |    2     | anne    | f
```

How do I formulate the condition statement for the select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`row_number()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

```
with my_table(id, group_id, name) as (
values
    (1, 1, 'richard'),
    (2, 1, 'ray'),
    (3, 2, 'enzo'),
    (4, 2, 'shiela'),
    (5, 2, 'anne')
)

select *, row_number() over w = 1 as is_first_row
from my_table
window w as (partition by group_id order by id);

 id | group_id |  name   | is_first_row 
----+----------+---------+--------------
  1 |        1 | richard | t
  2 |        1 | ray     | f
  3 |        2 | enzo    | t
  4 |        2 | shiela  | f
  5 |        2 | anne    | f
(5 rows)
```

---

Select `row_number()` to see how it works. Row numbers are calculated in partitions by `group_id` i.e. for every `group_id` separately, in order by `id`:

```
with my_table(id, group_id, name) as (
values
    (1, 1, 'richard'),
    (2, 1, 'ray'),
    (3, 2, 'enzo'),
    (4, 2, 'shiela'),
    (5, 2, 'anne')
)

select *, row_number() over w
from my_table
window w as (partition by group_id order by id);

 id | group_id |  name   | row_number 
----+----------+---------+------------
  1 |        1 | richard |          1
  2 |        1 | ray     |          2
  3 |        2 | enzo    |          1
  4 |        2 | shiela  |          2
  5 |        2 | anne    |          3
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Wow! that was really quick, I've looked at the documentation regarding "over" clause and "partition by" but couldn't make sense of it right now, would you mind showing how it works in this context? thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

please check my answer and let me know in case of any error in the logic

```
Create Table #Temp(id int,group_id int,name nvarchar(max))

 Insert into #Temp values
 (1,1,'richard')
,(2,1,'ray')
,(3,2,'enzo')
,(4,2,'shiela')
,(5,2,'anne')

Select t2.id,t2.group_id,t2.name,t1.group_id_c, case
when t1.group_id_c=1 then 't'
else 'f'
end  AS is_firstrow from #temp t2 join 
(Select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group_id order by id) as group_id_c from #Temp t ) t1
on t1.id=t2.id
```